# Using Microsoft Access program to upload images to be stored in SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, image, ms-access, varbinary

I have an Access back-end that is going to be converted to SQL Server.  The front-end will stay the same using Access.  The issue I am having is how SQL Server handles images differently than MS Access.

Currently, a user adds a picture to the record via the attachment data type which, to my understanding, isn't possible in SQL Server.  I saw the image data type is deprecated which leaves `varbinary(MAX)` and/or filestream as the options.

I want to go with storing the images in the filesystem as the size is greater than 256KB, but I'm not finding any documentation about accomplishing that with an Access front-end.

Comment: You want to extract images to folder location?

Comment: If you use File Table SQL Server will expose a Windows file share for you to save the files in using filesystem APIs.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/blob/filetables-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#:~:text=%20A%20FileTable%20provides%20the%20following%20functionality%3A%20,of%20a%20FileTable%2C%20see%20FileTable%20Schema.%0AA...%20More%20

Comment: If it's possible to have the image be visible instead of the file-path while the user is in the Access front-end, that'd be ideal.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Consider running an MS Access [pass-through query](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42) to upload user's image. Specifically, pass the file name into an SQL query as shown in [MSDN docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/sql/modifying-large-value-max-data) for large-value data types. For this, the user will need `OPENROWSET` privileges and the image file may need to be accessible on client machine or server.

```sql
INSERT myTable (myImageColumn, ...other columns...)  
SELECT myPicData.*, ...other values...  
FROM OPENROWSET
     (BULK 'C:\Path\To\Image.jpg', SINGLE_BLOB) AS myPicData
```